# Calling pdb's jump command while debugging in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pdb

For the most part, the pycharm's debugger UI is very helpful.

There is one piece missing from pdb that is fairly useful however, the jump command.

I know pycharm is not going to implement any time soon: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FPY-14306

Is there anyway to call the jump command "j" while the pycharm debugger is actively debugging?

Comment: They've marked the link you gave as a duplicate of [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9537#tab=Linked%20Issues) issue. If it's a feature you would like, I recommend voting on it (the little thumbs up). I think they do use that to determine priority for new features.